# Upgrading org.testcontainers from 1.10.6 to 1.15.1 - PostgreSQLContainer.start() dissapears

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, dependencies, testcontainers

I upgraded my org.testcontainers:

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
          <version>1.15.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

but then I can't use the start() method anymore:

```
public class ComponentTest {
      public static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgreDBContainer = new 
                PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:13");
      static {
        postgreDBContainer.start();
      }
}
```

Is there any solution to that issue?

Answer (score 1):

May be you missed  additional dependency?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>1.15.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```